# TypeError: string indices must be integers using pandas apply with lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, series

I have a dataframe, one column is a URL, the other is a name.  I'm simply trying to add a third column that takes the URL, and creates an HTML link.

The column `newsSource` has the Link name, and `url` has the URL.  For each row in the dataframe, I want to create a column that has:

```
<a href="[the url]">[newsSource name]</a>
```

Trying the below throws the error

> File "C:\Users\AwesomeMan\Documents\Python\MISC\News Alerts\simple_news.py", line 254, in 
>       df['sourceURL'] = df['url'].apply(lambda x: '{1}'.format(x, x[0]['newsSource']))
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
df['sourceURL'] = df['url'].apply(lambda x: '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(x, x['source']))
```

But I've used `x[colName]` before?  The below line works fine, it simply creates a column of the source's name:

```
df['newsSource'] = df['source'].apply(lambda x: x['name'])
```

Why suddenly ("suddenly" to me) is it saying I can't access the indices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) has access only to a single series, i.e. the series on which you are calling the method. In other words, the function you supply, irrespective of whether it is named or an anonymous `lambda`, will only have access to `df['source']`.

To access multiple series by row, you need [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) along `axis=1`:

```
def return_link(x):
    return '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(x['url'], x['source'])

df['sourceURL'] = df.apply(return_link, axis=1)
```

Note there is an overhead associated with passing an entire series in this way; `pd.DataFrame.apply` is just a thinly veiled, inefficient loop.

You may find a list comprehension more efficient:

```
df['sourceURL'] = ['<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(i, j) \
                   for i, j in zip(df['url'], df['source'])]
```

Here's a working demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['BBC', 'http://www.bbc.o.uk']],
                  columns=['source', 'url'])

def return_link(x):
    return '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(x['url'], x['source'])

df['sourceURL'] = df.apply(return_link, axis=1)

print(df)

  source                  url                              sourceURL
0    BBC  http://www.bbc.o.uk  <a href="http://www.bbc.o.uk">BBC</a>
```

Comment: Woah, thanks for this.  Very interesting!  I am learning pandas, so will have to unpack how the function works, but doing that straight doesn't.  One thing, the URL output is `https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/44807027">BBC News` instead of just `BBC News` with a link embedded?

Answer (score 2):

With zip and string old school string format

```
df['sourceURL'] = ['<a href="%s.">%s.</a>' % (x,y) for x , y in zip (df['url'], df['source'])]
```

This is `f-string`

```
[f'<a href="{x}">{y}</a>' for x , y in zip ((df['url'], df['source'])]
```