# Got TypeError: string indices must be integers with .apply

Tags: pandas, string, apply

I wrote the apply function below to perform regex-related operations and store the result in `email_account_letter_or_number_only` column. Basically, if the `email_account` is all numbers or if it contains no letters, then just store `email_account` for `email_account_letter_or_number_only`. Else, perform `re.sub` to only keep letters (in other words, remove all numbers and special characters) for `email_account_letter_or_number_only`.

```
concised_df['email_account_letter_or_number_only'] = concised_df['email_account'].apply(lambda x: x['email_account'] if (str(x['email_account']).isdigit() or not bool(re.search('[a-zA-Z]', str(x['email_account'])))) else re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', '', x['email_account']))
```

However, I got the `TypeError: string indices must be integers` error.

When I used the `df.iterrows()` method below, I was able to get the result without any error:

```
for index, row in concised_df.iterrows():
    if str(row['email_account']).isdigit() or not bool(re.search('[a-zA-Z]', str(row['email_account']))):
        concised_df.at[index, 'email_account_letter_or_number_only'] = row['email_account']
    else:
        concised_df.at[index, 'email_account_letter_or_number_only'] = re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', '', row['email_account'])
```

| email_account | email_account_letter_or_number_only |
| --- | --- |
| 0018889 | 0018889 |
| nacho.taro | nachotaro |
| nachth45678 | nachth |
| nacikita | nacikita |
| nacia_art | naciaart |

I really hope to use the `.apply` function since it's likely more efficient than `iterrows`, but the error was preventing me from using it. Could anyone please advise on what I might've done wrong in the `.apply` function?

Comment: Inside the apply, change `concised_df` to `x`, because the operation needs to be specified on the current row, not the entire column.

Comment: @cs95, I changed it to `concised_df['email_account'].apply(lambda x: x['email_account'] if (str(x['email_account']).isdigit() or not bool(re.search('[a-zA-Z]', str(x['email_account'])))) else re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', '', x['email_account']))`, but got error: TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Comment: That's a different error, perhaps update your question

Comment: Perhaps you can add `axis=1` as an argument to `.apply`, it should work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564120/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-using-pandas-apply-with-lambda) for more info

Comment: After adding `axis=`, I got a new error: TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: I think you accidentally added it inside the inner parentheses, if you do `df.apply(lambda x: (...), axis=1)` it will work

Comment: Thanks @cs95. I tried `concised_df.apply(lambda x: x['email_account'] if (str(x['email_account']).isdigit() or not bool(re.search('[a-zA-Z]', str(x['email_account'])))) else (re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', '', x['email_account'])), axis=1)` and it worked. Is there a way I can accept your answer so you get the credit?

Comment: not if I posted a comment, but you can upvote the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564120/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-using-pandas-apply-with-lambda) as they explain the same detail.